# Cannot initialize an object loaded via requireJS

Tags: javascript, requirejs

When I try to initialize an object declared/defined in a different file (but I believe it's been loaded via requireJS), it gives me `ReferenceError: myTemplates is not defined`. I have two files: `main.js` and `templates.js`.

In `main.js` (which is where I would like to load the object from `templates.js` and initialize it,

```
define(["jquery-ui", "templates"], function () {

  var templates = new myTemplates();     // gives ReferenceError
  alert( "Never reached this call" + $().jquery);

  $(document).ready(function() {
    alert( "Never reached this call " + $().jquery);
  });

});
```

In `templates.js`, which just have an object named `myTemplates` with a function named `test` as follows

```
define(["jquery-ui"], function () {
  alert( "This alert is raised, proving that jQuery/jQuery UI is loaded in templates.js " + $().jquery);

  function myTemplates(){
    this.test = function(){
      alert('test');
      return false;
    };
  };
});
```

For the config file for requireJS, named `requireconfig.js`, I have

```
requirejs.config({
  "baseUrl": "scripts/lib",
  "paths": {
    "app": "../app",
    "jquery" : [
        "//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min", 
        "jquery-1.10.2.min"],
    "jquery-ui" : [
        "//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min",
        "jquery-ui-1.10.3.min"],
    "templates" : "../app/templates/templates"
  },

  shim: {
    "jquery-ui": {
       exports: "$",
       deps: ["jquery"]},
  }
});
requirejs(["app/main", "templates"]);
```

I'm pretty sure the jQuery and jQuery UIs are loaded properly in `templates.js`, but I can't understand why I'm getting `ReferenceError` for initializing `myTemplates` in `main.js`. Could anyone please take a look and help me out. Thank you.

p.s. The [Github upload of the files/folders is here](https://github.com/programmertote/demo) in case anyone wants to look at the folder/file hierarchy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, two problems

in `templates.js`, once you defined a object, or function, you have to return it

```
function myTemplates(){ ... };
return myTemplates;
```

in `main.js`, you have to give a reference name for those defined objects, unless they are not AMD or defined in shim config.

```
define(["jquery-ui", "templates"], function ($ui, myTemplates)
```

give a try!

Comment: Thank you @Cauliturtle. I followed your suggestion above and it works! Is it possible to make the function `myTemplates`, an AMD and if so, could you please give me a brief answer or direct me to a guide online? Thank you again.

Comment: yes, your approach has no problem. But I suggest you to use `Backbone.js`, which help you easy to care about your `view`.

Comment: Thank you, @Cauliturtle. I've read about `Backbone.js`, but seems like it's time I learn it. :) Thank you for taking time to contribute to StackOverflow to pass down the knowledge and help others.